# Clearing state es6 React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to clear a components `state` but can't find a reference for the es6 syntax. I was using:

`this.replaceState(this.getInitialState());`

however this does not work with the es6 class syntax.

How would I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, React components don't keep a copy of the initial state, so you'll just have to do it yourself.

```
const initialState = {
    /* etc */
};

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = initialState;
    }
    reset() {
        this.setState(initialState);
    }
    /* etc */
}
```

Beware that the line `this.state = initialState;` requires you never to mutate your state, otherwise you'll pollute `initialState` and make a reset impossible. If you can't avoid mutations, then you'll need to create a copy of `initialState` in the constructor. (Or make `initialState` a function, as per `getInitialState()`.)

Finally, I'd recommend you use `setState()` and not `replaceState()`.

Comment: This is the method I use. I do want to comment that `replaceState` is perfectly fine in this scenario, as it ensures that the _entirety_ of the state object returns to a known set of values.

Comment: Actually it turns out that `replaceState()` isn't even available when using ES6 classes. I've only become aware of this in the time since I posted this answer.

Comment: Be aware that `setState` merges the state. If component adds fields to state that are not in `initialState`, those will not be cleared.

Comment: If you're adding fields to state that weren't defined in your initial state, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh What do you mean by never mutate your state? I take that to mean not ever using `this.setState()`, but that can't be right.

Comment: I mean always use `setState()` and never directly assign `this.state` (except to initialise it) and never directly mutate any state fields.

Comment: this doesn't work properly, because if you change `state` then it also changes `initialState` because it was assigned by reference. So when you call reset it actually doesn't reset to `initialState`. Nothing changes, you have to deep copy `initialState` to `state`

Comment: RaptoX, I covered this point in my original answer. If you're changing state by reference, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Hoknimo, this objection has been dealt with ad nauseum. If you update your state in an immutable manner (and you should be) you won't have any problems. If that's too difficult, then wrap your initial state in a function that always returns a fresh object.

Comment: I would place initialState as a class member instead of a global member.

Answer (score 66):

## Problem

The **accepted answer**:

```
const initialState = {
    /* etc */
};

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = initialState;
    }
    reset() {
        this.setState(initialState);
    }
    /* etc */
}
```

unfortunately is **not correct**.

`initialState` is passed as a reference to `this.state`, so whenever you change `state` you also change `initialState` (**const** doesn't really matter here). The result is that you can never go back to `initialState`.

## Solution

You have to **deep copy** `initialState` to `state`, then it will work. Either write a deep copy function yourself or use some existing module like [this](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/clone-deep).

Comment: You are right. 
Also this is the reason why Immutable.js (and other immutable libraries) exists.

Comment: Under the hood, React is doing an `Object.assign({}, nextState, partialState);`. So, is not necessary to do a deep copy of initialState, because this.state always is a new object after the setState.

 Ok, the Object.assign only clones one level... But all the saved state with the setState method should be without mutate the state, passing a new copy with the changes.

Comment: If this answer was correct, I would be having an issue when I set the state to the initial state and then try to reset it again.  But that is not happening at all.  The users who voted on this answer do not truly understand what is going on.  I'm so frustrated right now that so many people have been duped by this dubious understanding, especially since it's so easy to test.

Comment: I have a doubt? Why can't we initiate an empty state in the constructor and later update our initialState in componentDidMount? Does using lifecycles methods cause any problem? 
If this works then we can easily update the initialState later on.

Comment: Unless you're mutating the state yourself (aka, code smell), using the same `initialState` object reference is totally fine.

Answer (score 43):

This is the solution implemented as a function:

```
Class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getInitialState();
  }

  getInitialState = () => ({
    /* state props */
  })

  resetState = () => {
     this.setState(this.getInitialState());
  }
}
```

Comment: With this option, I don't need to make a deep copy.

Comment: This solution is simple and easy to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The solutions that involve setting `this.state` directly aren't working for me in React 16, so here is what I did to reset each key:

```
  const initialState = { example: 'example' }
  ...
  constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = initialState
  }
  ...
  reset() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.state)
    const stateReset = keys.reduce((acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v]: undefined }), {})
    this.setState({ ...stateReset, ...initialState })
  }
```

Comment: variant for select-like state

const keys = Object.keys(this.state);
const stateReset = keys.reduce((acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v]: false }), {});
this.setState(stateReset);

Comment: Unlike the higher voted answers above, this solution actually clears any state elements no longer declared in the initial state. Kudos!

Comment: Yes this is a good answer, if you don't do this other state that's set after initialization will still be there.

Answer (score 5):

First, you'll need to store your initial state when using the `componentWillMount()` function from the component lifecycle:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.initialState = this.state
}
```

This stores your initial state and can be used to reset the state whenever you need by calling

```
this.setState(this.initialState)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I handle it:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this._initState = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
      }
    this.state = this._initState;
  }

  _resetState(){
     this.setState(this._initState);
   }
}
```

**Update:** 
Actually this is wrong. For future readers please refer to @RaptoX answer. 
Also, you can use an Immutable library in order to prevent weird state modification caused by reference assignation.

Comment: Wouldn't `this._initState` be undefined in your constructor? Did you mean `this.state = this._initialState`?

Answer (score 4):

```
const initialState = {
    a: '',
    b: '',
    c: ''
};

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
    state = { ...initialState } // use spread operator to avoid mutation
    handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);

    handleReset() {
         this.setState(initialState);
    }
 }
```

Remember that in order to be able to reset the state it is important not to mutate initialState.

```
state = {...initialState} // GOOD 
// => state points to a new obj in memory which has the values of initialState

state = initialState // BAD 
// => they point to the same obj in memory
```

The most convenient way would be to use ES6 Spread Operator. But you could also use Object.assign instead. They would both achieve the same.

```
state = Object.assign({}, initialState); // GOOD
state = {...initialState}; // GOOD
```

Answer (score 4):

In most cases you dont need a deep copy, rarely initial state is object of objects, so using spread operator which babel transpiles to the object.assign should be fine.

So, inside constructor you would have:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            key: value,
            key2: value
        }
        this.initialState = { ...this.state } 
    }
}
```

From there you can use

```
this.setState(this.initialState);
```

to reset. But if for some reason your initial state is more complex object, use some library.

Answer (score 0):

I will add to the above answer that the reset function should also assign state like so:

```
reset() {
  this.state = initialState;
  this.setState(initialState);
}
```

The reason being that if your state picks up a property that wasn't in the initial state, that key/value won't be cleared out, as setState just updates existing keys.  Assignment is not enough to get the component to re-render, so include the setState call as well -- you could even get away with this.setState({}) after the assignment.

Comment: This seems like overkill. Is this really the way one should do this?

Comment: You are mutating state outside of the React lifecycle... This is incorrect React.

Comment: You should not do `this.state = initialState;`

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances, it's sufficient to just set all values of `state` to `null`.

If you're state is updated in such a way, that you don't know what might be in there, you might want to use

```
this.setState(Object.assign(...Object.keys(this.state).map(k => ({[k]: null}))))
```

Which will change the state as follows

```
{foo: 1, bar: 2, spam: "whatever"} > {foo: null, bar: null, spam: null}
```

Not a solution in all cases, but works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your state object, loop through each one, and set it to `undefined`. This method is not as good as the accepted answer, though.

```
const clonedState = this.state;

const keys = Object.keys(clonedState);
keys.forEach(key => (clonedState[key] = undefined));

this.setState(clonedState);
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
   this.state = {
     inputVal: props.inputValue
  }
   // preserve the initial state in a new object
   this.baseState = this.state 
}
  resetForm = () => {
    this.setState(this.baseState)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use deep copy, you can do it with lodash:

```
import _ from "lodash";

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = _.cloneDeep(INITIAL_STATE);
}

reset() {
    this.setState(_.cloneDeep(INITIAL_STATE));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class x extends Components {
constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {

  name: 'mark',
  age: 32,
  isAdmin: true,
  hits: 0,

  // since this.state is an object
  // simply add a method..

  resetSelectively() {
         //i don't want to reset both name and age
    // THIS IS FOR TRANSPARENCY. You don't need to code for name and age
    // it will assume the values in default..
    // this.name = this.name;   //which means the current state.
    // this.age = this.age;


    // do reset isAdmin and hits(suppose this.state.hits is 100 now)

    isAdmin = false;
    hits = 0;
  }// resetSelectively..

}//constructor..

/* now from any function i can just call */
myfunction() {
  /**
   * this function code..
   */
   resetValues();

}// myfunction..

resetValues() {
  this.state.resetSelectively();
}//resetValues

/////
//finally you can reset the values in constructor selectively at any point

...rest of the class..

}//class
```