# How do you reset state when keys are not known? (i.e. dynamic forms)

Tags: reactjs

I'm using es6 syntax `setState({[name]: value})` to track dynamically added inputs in form and everything is working fine. I'm wondering about clearing state after form submit. I'll submit my solution but I'd be interested in hearing opinions on a better way of clearing the state, or maybe managing dynamic state shape in general.

According to @DavidL.Walsh (see link below) adding fields to state that were not defined in initial state is wrong. But what about dynamic forms in which you don't know the number of inputs or their names.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34845925/4634544

Comment: If the form state were in an object itself, then you could just reset the object.

Comment: @Rick Jolly Ok so nest the state, cool, that works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am currently using. All the items I'm tracking are strings, which is nice.

```
Object.keys(this.state).forEach(key => {
    this.setState({[key]: ''})
})
```

Comment: if you want to keep mutating the keys of your state (which is an antipattern) then you can at least make this more robust.. add type checking for the state variable to then reset to a default. I would still recommend that you dont do this approach. can cause unexpected bugs in your code

Comment: How does this mutate the keys of the state object? Isn't it simply setting the value of all the existing keys? I hear ya on the more robust thing... I was hinting at the fact that this was only useful for string value.

Comment: The code here isn't.. but you are dynamically adding them somewhere this is what i was referring to

Answer (score 0):

fyi, @Rick Jolly's idea is to nest the form state. So initial state would be:
`state = { form: {} }`

Updating state would look like:
`this.setState(prevState => ({ form: { ...prevState.form, [name]: value } 
 }))`

And resetting state would look like:
`this.setState({ form: {} })`

Thanks Rick!

Comment: This is not a good idea.. because that means that your mutating the data type for every input when you reset state.. meaning initially the state was a type string but now is undefined.. so your `<input value={this.state.form.something} />` changes from a string to undefined.. you are also mutating the keys of your state which is not something you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you define a state in a React Component you would define all of the keys and their initial value on mount / construct. you can encapsulate this data to a constant that you use to reset

#### Using a login form as an example

```
const LOGIN_INITIAL_STATE = { username: '', password: '', rememberEmail: false } 

// in the class
this.state = {...LOGIN_INITIAL_STATE}

// to reset
this.setState({...LOGIN_INITIAL_STATE})
```

If you dont know the fields for the form, I would not render the form until you get those fields. Pass them as an initial state property.. in the constructor you can then define the state with the initial state property. That way you define the state on construct instead of adding fields in after defining state (which David Walsh recommends because its a bad practice)

#### Dynamic form example

```
someRequestToGetFormFields().then(fields => dispatch({type: FIELDS_ADDED, fields})
// in a reducer you store these fields and update the state of the reducer.

// in a class that renders the form
{ this.props.formFields
  ? <SomeDynamicForm initialState={this.props.formFields} />
  : null 
}

// your form class
class SomeDynamicForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {...props.initialState}
    }
    resetState = () => {
        this.setState({...this.props.initialState})
    }
    ...
}
```

Now this is a quick and not exhaustive solution.. You should be able to figure out the rest from here though.

Comment: Thanks John, what about a dynamic form in the sense that the user adds inputs as needed? Like a form builder or something.

Comment: @spflow dont use state for that.. use props.. create a new item in your reducer when they want a new input.. use the props that come in to render new items

Comment: OK, so you're assuming use of redux or some other state store? Ok, so a new item is added to redux, the props to the form component is updated and now I have additional data to create another input. How does this change anything? I want to track the state of that input in the form component. I must add another piece to the component state object. The component is already mounted. De-mount? Limit state to each individual input? Move all form state to redux? Not sure I see your solution. Sorry, maybe I'm sluggish from weekend.

Comment: Well it depends on how you implement it.. my assumption is that this way you don't add any new keys to your state. You push to an array a new item that your view uses to render a new input.. for instance let's say you make a class for a drop-down component and a class for free text, a class for check box... Etc (not a react class just a regular class to store data and metadata).. when the user says they want a new field for the form you push to an array in your store a new instance of the correct class that the user selects.. kinda like a survey system.