# React how to delete properties from state

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-16

I'm trying to replace whole state or at least delete all properties from it.

Before react 16 I just called these two lines

```
this.state = {}
this.forceUpdate()
```

With update to react 16, this didn't work anymore.
Currently I have this workaround in shouldComponentUpdate Method:

```
for (let prop in nextState) { 
    if (nextState.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
        delete nextState[prop]; 
    } 
}
```

But this 'feels' not right. So does anybody know the right way to reset whole state with new object? As far as I tested this.setState just changes the differences and leave other properties untouched.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46116588/4467208

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I tried that already, but every property which is in state but not in initialState remains in this.state unchanged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove properties from the state, because it internally uses a merge

```
nextState = Object.assign({}, nextState, partialState);
```

So no way of removing already present keys. Only thing you can do is set the current keys to undefined.
If you know the properties, you can set them manually.

If not, you can try this to set them all to undefined:

```
this.setState(
  Object.keys(this.state).reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c] = undefined;
    return a;
  }, {})
)
```

Comment: Thank your for the clarification. Unfortunately i can't use this workaround because i ask for the existince of the keys, even if they are undefined.

So i need to reprogram the component so it gets completely reloaded when i need the reset.