# How to change one state and clear all other states?

Tags: reactjs

I have a state interface including many states.
By clicking a button I want to set one of the states and clear all others to their initial value. I used this approach [for writing an intial state and keep a copy of the initial state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845650/clearing-state-es6-react) but any time I use it I have to hardcode my new state's value like this:
In constructor after initializing my state I create a copy of the initial state:

`this.baseState = this.state;`

then anytime I need to clear the state to its initial value I have to

```
this.baseState.someStateName = someStateValue;
this.setState(this.baseState);
```

What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Showing us 2 lines of code isn't enough information - is this in the constructor? and what is viewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
this.setState(Object.assign({}, defaultState(), {someStateName: someStateValue}));
```

For more override values, keep appending to the right if you wish.